# Why does a Box pointer passed to C and back to Rust segfault?

Tags: rust, ffi

Some C code calls into the Rust `open` call below which returns a pointer.  Later the C code passes the exact same pointer back to the `close` function which tries to drop (free) it.  It segfaults in `free(3)`.  Why?

```
use std::os::raw::{c_int, c_void};

struct Handle;

extern "C" fn open(_readonly: c_int) -> *mut c_void {
    let h = Handle;
    let h = Box::new(h);
    return Box::into_raw(h) as *mut c_void;
}

extern "C" fn close(h: *mut c_void) {
    let h = unsafe { Box::from_raw(h) };
    // XXX This segfaults - why?
    drop(h);
}
```

Comment: Please use `rustfmt` to ensure that your code matches the style guidelines

Comment: Please note, that this has nothing to do with `extern "C"`. It segfaults nevertheless https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3cedf8eca72de930e79d093ea22a9212

Comment: How can I make the Box not be dropped?  Although in the example my handle is empty, in the real code I want to return a handle which is passed back later to other functions, then freed in close.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to call it?  It seems like `leak` returns the inner T, but that can't be cast to the final `void*`

Comment: Oddly, this only seems to segfault when `Handle` is zero-sized.

Comment: Adding some more debugging to the C side shows that the pointer returned by open == `0x1` which is obviously completely wrong.  This does explain why it crashes in the close function, but not why `Box::into_raw` returns a non-pointer ...

Comment: OK it turns out the whole code works if I put some dummy fields in the handle (without using `leak`).

Comment: @E4_net_or_something_like_that `Box::into_raw` "forgets" the `Box`, so the `Box` is *not* dropped when `open` returns.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In `close`, you end up creating a `Box<c_void>` instead of a `Box<Handle>` because you didn't cast the `*mut c_void` back to `*mut Handle` before invoking `Box::from_raw`.

```
fn close(h: *mut c_void) {
    let h = unsafe { Box::from_raw(h as *mut Handle) };
    //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    drop(h);
}
```

By the way, `Box` doesn't actually allocate any memory for a zero-sized type (such as `Handle` here) and uses a fixed, non-zero pointer value instead (which, in the current implementation, is the alignment of the type; a zero-sized type has an alignment of 1 by default). The destructor for a boxed zero-sized type knows not to try to deallocate memory at this fictitious memory address, but `c_void` is not a zero-sized type (it has size 1), so the destructor for `Box<c_void>` tries to free memory at address `0x1`, which causes the segfault.

If `Handle` wasn't zero-sized, then the code may not crash, but it would still run the wrong destructor (it'd run `c_void`'s destructor, which does nothing), and this may cause memory leaks. A destructor runs `Drop::drop` for the type if present, then drops the type's fields.

Comment: Ah! I was still searching *why* it segfaults to add in my answer. I suspected something like that, but wasn't sure yet. I beat you by a few minutes, but your answer is much better!

Answer (score 7):

The problem is you didn't cast the pointer back to a `Handle` pointer while transforming it back to a `Box`, and got a `Box` of the wrong type.

This works:

```
fn close(h: *mut c_void) {
    let h = unsafe { Box::from_raw(h as *mut Handle) };
    //                               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    drop(h);
}
```

In your code, `h` is a `std::boxed::Box<std::ffi::c_void>`.